# Symfony3 foreach causes local server to crash

Tags: php, symfony, foreach, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two tables in one database that are emptied and replaced very frequently. Each table has well over 65,000 rows. I want to select two fields from the first table (**LnsPriceUpdates**), then take those values and compare and insert them into the second table (**LnsCatalog**) and want to do this for all 65,000 items in the database.

*(Note: I want to do all this from a localhost)*

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
public function testbananaAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT l.partnumber, l.level1Net FROM AppBundle:LnsPriceUpdates l WHERE l.level1Net IS NOT NULL'
        )
        ->getResult();


    foreach ($query as $row){
        $partNo = $row['partnumber'];
        $part = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Lnscatalog')
            ->findOneBy(['partnoid' => $partNo]);
        $dealerCost = $row['level1Net'];
        if(isset($dealerCost) && isset($part)){
            $partCheck = $part->getDealerCost();
            if(!isset($partCheck)){
                $part->setDealerCost($dealerCost);
                $em->flush();
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }

    }
    return new Response('yay');

}
```

Any ideas to accomplish this task without crashing would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you achieve with a single Sql Update something like:

```
update Lnscatalog c 
set c.dealerCost = (SELECT l.level1Net FROM AppBundle:LnsPriceUpdates l WHERE l.level1Net IS NOT NULL and l.partnumber=c.partnoid)
where c.dealerCost is null
and exists (SELECT l.level1Net FROM AppBundle:LnsPriceUpdates l WHERE l.level1Net IS NOT NULL and l.partnumber=c.partnoid)
```

You can speed up this query adding some index on the above table, as example:

```
ALTER TABLE LnsPriceUpdates 
 ADD INDEX LnsPriceUpdates_IDX_1 (level1Net, partnumber) ;

ALTER TABLE LnsPriceUpdates 
 ADD INDEX LnsPriceUpdates_IDX_2 (partnumber) ;

ALTER TABLE Lnscatalog 
 ADD INDEX Lnscatalog_IDX_2 (dealerCost) ;
```

Some reference about optimizing sql query can be found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1250/3-Ways-to-Speed-Up-MySQL.html), [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/writing-blazing-fast-mysql-queries--cms-25085) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this will work, the only issue is that it's been loading for 30 minutes

Comment: Try adding some sql index on field that are in the where conditions

Comment: I've never used index, could you shed some light on that for me?

Comment: That definitely sped things up, but now all of the values in dealercost are 1